# How to perform click on TextInputLayout EndIcon button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout

I know that it is possible to perform a click on a view like this :

```
view.PerformClick()
```

How do I do it on `TextInputLayout` EndIcon `button`?

**Update**

The problem is that I have a bunch of InputLayouts and use a generic function to set the click listeners on them like so

```
fun setTextInputLayoutListeners(
    inputLayout: TextInputLayout, editText: TextInputEditText,
    actionSet: () -> Unit,
    actionClear: () -> Unit
) {
    with (inputLayout) {
        setOnClickListener { actionSet() }
        setEndIconOnClickListener { actionClear() }
    }
    editText.setOnClickListener { actionSet() }
}
```

and call it with different parameteres like this

```
setTextInputLayoutListeners(
    categoryInputLayout, categoryEditText, { onCategoryClick() }, { onCategoryClear() }
)
setTextInputLayoutListeners(
    dateInputLayout, dateEditText, { onDateClick() }, { onDateClear(calendar) }
)
```

so I'm looking for a generic solution, sort of

```
inputLayout.EndIcon.PerformClick()
```

Comment: What is endIcon?

Comment: Do you mean DrawableEnd?

Answer (score 17):

```
textinput.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do some code
            }
        });
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

**EndIcon** in `TextInputLayout` is of type `CheckableImageButton` and its *id* is `R.id.text_input_end_icon` (use `R.id.text_input_start_icon` for **StartIcon**). To simulate clicks, you need to find the button using `findViewById`, then cast it as a `CheckableImageButton` and call `performClick()`.

In your case:

```
inputLayout.findViewById<CheckableImageButton>(R.id.text_input_end_icon)?.performClick()
```

Comment: Welcome! Providing some context or (short) explanation would help make your answer easier to understand and also more likely to be upvoted. Try to avoid code dump answers or questions.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me to get end icon view and perform click on it

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for you clear and helpful answer.I  did a  little trick that worked and i wanna share my answer to everyone who will need it.

First thing i did is get the string value of my view :

```
Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(v));
```

i got that  :  **com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton{ba604a VFED..C.. ...P.... 8,3-104,99 #7f090125 app:id/text_input_end_icon}**

and like i suspected then icon is a different view of the text field layout with different id (in the end of the string value of the view).
So i changed my if condition from **if (v.getId() == R.id.start_date_Layout)** to **if (v.getId() == R.id.text_input_end_icon)**, and it work now

i hope this answer will be helpful to someone, thank you again for all your answer