# Android : Add a listener to an icon in a text field

Tags: java, android, textfield

i am a beginner  in application development and i like to ask a question that i tried my best to get an answer in google but i failed.
So,

in my application (in java) i am using too text fields :

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/start_date_Layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        app:helperText="Start Date"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_date"

        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/start_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="dd/mm/yy"

            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I added a listener to my end icon like that :

```
this.startDateLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.start_date_Layout);
this.startDateLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener(this);
```

My problem is when i try to get the view that the user clicked :

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    
    if (v.getParent() == this.startDateLayout){
       
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
}
```

the toast never appear and the if condition is never true, my question is how can i get the view on witch the user clicked. thanks for reading i hope i was clear as much as possible.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59929046/5031209

Answer (score 25):

For me only doing following works:

```
final TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.start_date_Layout);
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // DO STUFF
    }
});
```

As you're explicitly setting listener on End icon only you shouldn't be worried about verifying viewId.

Comment: Don't forget to add clearing of `TextInputEditText`'s field inside the listener (in this case `<start_date>.text?.clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple kotlin:

```
    b.dateLabel.setEndIconOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First what I can notice in the above code, you're trying to listen  to click events on your View

A simple way to do so is change your **onClick()** method to below

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    
    if (v.getId() == R.id.start_date_Layout){
       
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    
}
```

I believe I could help

Comment: Still don't work, i think because the icon in the text field layout is another view, i tried to get the string value of the view and i get that : com.google.android.material.internal.CheckableImageButton{6bb58e VFED..C.. ...P.... 8,3-104,99 #7f090125 app:id/text_input_end_icon}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EditText, then try setting an onFocusChangeListner to the editText instead of onClickListner.

```
startDateLayout.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
       // Show your code when has focus
    } else {
       // when it does not have focus
    }
}});
```

Comment: But i want to set a listener for only the icon, and i will add another listener to the edit text (text field )

Answer (score 0):

The question is simple, You can you a **FragmeLayout** or **LinearLayout**, **EditText** and an **ImageView** for achieving the solution, it will be similar to the **TextInputEditText** but you will have much more control over View Hierarchy, let me show you how you can achieve it, for the sake of simplicity as you are a beginner I'll use linear Layout

**Create A `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout` and then create an `EditText` and an ImageView like**

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#DCDFDF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#DCDFDF"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Start Date"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextTitle;
    ImageView imageViewTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        imageViewTitle = findViewById(R.id.imageViewTitle);

          imageViewTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
             //Do your work here
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ImageView Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can obviously and to be honest with a minor effort you can achieve more from this than TextInputEditText.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer me, but i prefer to use a text field due to all his functionalities that a simple Edit text dont.